# how to auto reload during debuggin in pyDev

Tags: python, reload, pydev, edit-and-continue

I have PyDev 3.8+ on Eclipse and I can't get auto-reload to work.
I have checked all options in the PyDev > Debug > When file is changed, automatically reload module, but still I can't make it work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8SOY.png)

i want to change 'che' to some other number while debugging

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to reload the currently running function (that's a Python limitation).

So, you must reload before entering the function.

Also, in general, you should not need to call `pydevd_reload.xreload(mod)` yourself... whenever you change the file and save it while the debugger is running, PyDev should automatically reload it for you.

Also, keep in mind that reload has a number of limitations. See: https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/blob/main/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_reload.py#L66 for more details.